# create a xml in python having <?xml version="xxx"?>?

Tags: python, xml

There are plenty of examples in the web on how to create a xml with python. An examples is:

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc")

field1 = ET.SubElement(doc, "field1")
field1.set("name", "blah")
field1.text = "some value1"

field2 = ET.SubElement(doc, "field2")
field2.set("name", "asdfasd")
field2.text = "some vlaue2"

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

tree.write("filename.xml")
```

But this creates a document starting with

```
<root>
```

and not with

```
<?xml version="xxx"?>
```

How can I add the

```
<?xml version="xxx"?>
```

bit to the XML?

Thanks,
Carlos.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Element Tree is removing the XML declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612648/python-element-tree-is-removing-the-xml-declaration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify `xml_declaration` and `encoding`:

```
tree.write("filename.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

According to [`ElementTree.write` documentation](http://xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write):

> `write(file, encoding="us-ascii", xml_declaration=None,
>   default_namespace=None, method="xml")`
>
> Writes the element tree to a file, as XML. file is a file name, or a
>   file object opened for writing. encoding is the output encoding
>   (default is US-ASCII). **xml_declaration** controls if an XML declaration
>   should be added to the file. Use False for never, True for always,
>   None for only if not US-ASCII or UTF-8 (default is None).
>   default_namespace sets the default XML namespace (for “xmlns”). method
>   is either "xml", "html" or "text" (default is "xml"). Returns an
>   encoded string.