# Filtering XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, filter, elementtree

I need to write a filter to discard some elements, tags and blocks in my XML Files. In the following you can see what are my xml examples and expected outputs. I am somehow confused about the differences between element, tag, attribute in the elemetTree. My test does not work!

Filter:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xee

def test(input):
    doc=xee.fromstring(input)
    print xee.tostring(doc)

    #RemoveTimeStampAttribute
    for elem in doc.findall('Component'):
        if 'timeStamp' in elem.attrib:
            del elem.attrib['timeStamp']

    #RemoveTimeStampElements
    for elem in doc.findall('TimeStamp'):
        del elem 
    print xee.tostring(doc) 
    return xee.tostring(doc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are removing the attribute incorrectly, see if `timeStamp` is in the element's [`attrib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib) dictionary and then use `del` to remove it:

```
def amdfilter(input):
    doc = xee.fromstring(input)

    for node in doc.findall('Component'):
        if 'timeStamp' in node.attrib:
            del node.attrib['timeStamp']

    return xee.tostring(doc)
```

Also, since you are testing only the attribute removal here, change your expectation to:

```
expected = '<ComponentMain><Component /></ComponentMain>'
```

Complete test (it passes):

```
import unittest
from amdfilter import *

class FilterTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testRemoveTimeStampAttribute(self):
        input = '<?xml version="1.0"?><ComponentMain><Component timeStamp="2014"></Component></ComponentMain>'
        output = amdfilter(input)
        expected = '<ComponentMain><Component /></ComponentMain>'
        self.assertEqual(expected, output)
```

Note that I don't care here about the xml declaration line ([it could be easily added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612648/python-element-tree-is-removing-the-xml-declaration)).

Comment: tnx, it works..just one question, is xml version tag removed when we revert the input to String?

Comment: And how to delete a node itself? Question is edited.

Comment: @OrclUser ok, `TimeStamp` can be anywhere in the xml, or at a specific location?

Comment: It is either an attribute or an element or a block..You can find in my examples, in the first one it is an attribute and I just need to remove that attribute, in the second one it is an element and I need to remove the whole element and in the third one the whole block.